Help with a partial differential equation - inaccurate result
I'm trying to solve the following partial differential equation using NDSolve
sol = NDSolve[
  {D[umax[t, r], t] - (r/(2*f[t])*f'[t])*D[umax[t, r], r] == HeavisideTheta[u[f[t], g[t], r] - umax[t, r]]*HeavisideTheta[f[t]*f'[t] - f'[t]/((f[t])^2) - (r^2*g[t]^2)/(2*f[t])*f'[t] + r^2*g[t]*g'[t]]*Abs[f[t]*f'[t] - f'[t]/((f[t])^2) - (r^2*g[t]^2)/(2*f[t])*f'[t] + r^2*g[t]*g'[t]] , 
umax[t, 0] == 0, umax[0, r] == 0}, umax, {t, 0, 5}, {r, 0, 1}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxSteps -> Infinity]

where
f[t_] := 1 + 1/5*t*(Cos[t])^2  
g[t_] := 1/5*t*(Cos[t])^2  

and
u[f_, g_, r_] := f^2 + 2/f + r^2 g^2 - 3

The purpose of this equation is to calculate the maximum historical values $u_{max}$ of the function $u$ for a given $r$.
For smaller values of $r$, for example $r = 0.1$, everything works as expected:

But when I take larger values close to one, e.g. $r = 0.9$, the result becomes inaccurate. On the interval (approximately) $[3.5 ; 5.5]$, where the graph of the $u_{max}$ function should be a straight line, you can see the inaccuracy in the sag:

I'm sure the partial differential equation is formulated correctly. It's physically motivated, so I can't change it.
But I would like to ask for help on how to improve the code so that the Wolfram Mathematica calculates what I require? I have tried increasing AccurancyGoal and PrecisionGoal, but to no effect.
Thank you very much for your help.

Even with r=0.1, it's not quite a straight line between ~3.5 and 5.5
